# Prove that:$u_n$ and $v_n$ adjacent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

WE have two sequence
$V_n=(1+\frac{1} {n}) (u_n) $

And

$u_n=\prod\limits_{1}^{n}(1+\frac{1} {k^2})$

I know that : $\lim_{n\to+\infty} v_n-u_n=0$

I want to prove $u_n$ is incremental and $v_n$ is diminishing for say : $u_n$ and $v_n $ adjacent

For $u_n$:

$ln(u_n) =\sum_{1}^{n}\frac{k^2 +1}{k^2} =2+\frac{5}{4}+\frac{10} {9}+.... +\frac{n^2 +1}{n^2} $

$ln(u_(n+1)) =\sum_{1}^{n+1}\frac{k^2 +1}{k^2} =2+\frac{5}{4}+\frac{10} {9}+.... +\frac{(n+1)^2 +1}{(n+1)^2} $

$\Rightarrow$$\frac{u_(n+1)}{u_n}=e^{\frac{1+(n+1)^2} {(n+1)^2}} >1 $

$\Rightarrow $$u_(n+1)>u_n$
$u_n$ is incremental sequence

For $V_n:$
$V_n=(1+\frac{1} {n}) (u_n) $

I am proved that : $v_(n+1)-v_(n)=\frac{(u_(n+1)-u_n)(n^2 +2n)-u_n}{n(n+1)}$

And I US other ideas but I don't know how we can show $v_n$ is diminishing

Finally:

I want to prove $v_n$ is diminishing

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You want to prove that
$$\ln(V_{n+1})\le \ln(V_n)$$

or equivalently

$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n+1})+\ln(U_{n+1})\le$$
$$\ln(1+\frac 1n)+\ln(U_n)$$

or

$$\ln(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2})\le \ln(\frac{U_n}{U_{n+1}})$$

and

$$\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\le \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2+1}$$

This last inequality is always true.
use for this
$$(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$$

Comment: YES. THANK YOU.

Comment: @hamam-abdallah I PROVE THAT$  \frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}<1$ because$ \frac{u_n}{u_(n+1)}<1 $ s o$v_n$ is diminishing is that correct?

Comment: @Amath My last inequality is equivalent to $ v_{n+1}\le v_n$.

Comment: i see the 3 inequality is equivalent  $v_(n+1)<v_n$ and i see the last is  equivalente $\frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{u_n}{u_(n+1)}<1$ so it is enought show $\frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}<1$?